# How to fwrite() two different kinds of variables within a struct?

Tags: c, struct, fwrite

I'd like to add an array of type 'struct classes' (definition included below) to a file. For instance, if `allClasses[0].title` is equal to "Math" and `allClasses[0].class_id` is equal to 1, I'd like the file to have the following input:

`1Math/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0`

If another class is added with a title of Science, then the file should now read

`1Math/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/02Science/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0`

What appears to happen is that, although the code will catch the char array part of the struct (math / science in the example), it will have trouble with the int and instead print out junk in its place (and the junk is often times longer than 1 character / 1 int long).

From experience, the code format (with a few adjustments, of course) works just fine when using a struct with variables that are only char arrays. However, it glitches out when using ints. Is this because of ASCII conversions, or something similar? How can I adjust the code so that I get the input with both the int and the char array?

```
void addClasses(char *given_title) {

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("classes.db", "r");

if (numClasses == 0 && fp != NULL) {
    findClasses();
}

strcpy(allClasses[numClasses].title, given_title);
allClasses[numClasses].class_id = numClasses + 1;
numClasses++;

fclose(fp);

fp = fopen("classes.db", "w");

for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
    struct classes *object = malloc(sizeof(struct classes) - 1);
    memset(object, 0, sizeof( struct classes ));

    object->class_id = allClasses[i].class_id;
    strcpy(object->title, allClasses[i].title);

    fseek(fp, numClasses * (sizeof(struct classes) - 1), SEEK_END);
    fwrite(object, sizeof(struct classes) - 1, 1, fp);
}
fclose( fp );
}
```

The struct:

```
struct classes {
   int class_id;
   char title[30];
};
```

A bit of extra (possibly unnecessary) background on some of the components in the code: the bit at the beginning of the method tries to read the file and start to fill the array with any structs that were already put into the file before starting the program. I'm not including the code for that, since the aforementioned glitch happens even when I have a fresh classes.db file (and thus, even when `findClasses()` never runs).

Small note, by the way: I can't change the class_id into a char / char array. It needs to be an int.

Comment: do you want to have a text file or raw binary. It is very hard to understand what you mean

Comment: The first member of your structure is an `int`, which is at least two bytes wide (probably 4).  `fwrite()` performs an unformatted, raw write, so it will write all four (or whatever) bytes of that member each time.  This will be the machine representation, not human-readable text.  If that's not what you want, then neither is `fwrite()`.

Comment: @P__J__ Text file, I believe...? I don't think binary is the right thing for what I need to do with the file.

Comment: What do you want? Human readable text or binary data?

Comment: @JohnBollinger what would be the alternative to `fwrite()`? I just need something that can store \0 chars, the int, and the char array, and then to be able to read the file and get the same thing as the input.

Comment: @Swordfish Human readable, probably. It's meant to be a storage container for the data the program uses, and to remember what classes were previously inputted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add it in the text form:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d,\"%s\"\n", object -> class_id, object -> title);
```

when you open the file with "w" you create new empty file. When you write to the file you do need to fseek.

If you want to append to existing file use "a" or "a+" instead.

Comment: Definitely do not want to append -- the emptying of the file is intentional. Since I'll be using "w", will I need to fseek every time the loop iterates, or just once before the for loop?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify in case it mattered in your response. Do I need to fseek every time the loop iterates?